# what is collation? what is the need of it in database? in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am going through mysql (through xampp phpamin)database I found there. I found there create database and collation. What is collation, Why we need that while creating  new database. can any one explain

Comment: Have you read the mysql documentation?

Comment: I read that, There I understand something bout data sorting

Answer (score 1):

From: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-general.html

> A character set is a set of symbols and encodings. A collation is a
>   set of rules for comparing characters in a character set. Let's make
>   the distinction clear with an example of an imaginary character set.
>
> Suppose that we have an alphabet with four letters: A, B, a, b. We
>   give each letter a number: A = 0, B = 1, a = 2, b = 3. The letter A is
>   a symbol, the number 0 is the encoding for A, and the combination of
>   all four letters and their encodings is a character set.
>
> Suppose that we want to compare two string values, A and B. The
>   simplest way to do this is to look at the encodings: 0 for A and 1 for
>   B. Because 0 is less than 1, we say A is less than B. What we've just
>   done is apply a collation to our character set. The collation is a set
>   of rules (only one rule in this case): “compare the encodings.” We
>   call this simplest of all possible collations a binary collation.
>
> But what if we want to say that the lowercase and uppercase letters
>   are equivalent? Then we would have at least two rules: (1) treat the
>   lowercase letters a and b as equivalent to A and B; (2) then compare
>   the encodings. We call this a case-insensitive collation. It is a
>   little more complex than a binary collation.
>
> In real life, most character sets have many characters: not just A and
>   B but whole alphabets, sometimes multiple alphabets or eastern writing
>   systems with thousands of characters, along with many special symbols
>   and punctuation marks. Also in real life, most collations have many
>   rules, not just for whether to distinguish lettercase, but also for
>   whether to distinguish accents (an “accent” is a mark attached to a
>   character as in German Ö), and for multiple-character mappings (such
>   as the rule that Ö = OE in one of the two German collations).
>
> MySQL can do these things for you:
>
> - Store strings using a variety of character sets.
> - Compare strings using a variety of collations.
> - Mix strings with different character sets or collations in the same    server, the same database, or even the same table.
> - Enable specification of character set and collation at any level.
>
> To use these features effectively, you must know what character sets
>   and collations are available, how to change the defaults, and how they
>   affect the behavior of string operators and functions.

Comment: I got confused as there are plenty of functions in collation. what should we use